# Trying to find a multi-part story in a sci-fi magazine back in the 70's

Tags: story-identification

The magazine might have been Analog or Asimov's.  I don't recall a lot of details, but here's what I have:

- There where two characters initially, a man and a woman.
- Neither knew who they were or why they were there.
- They were in a house, surrounded by fields and wilderness, but eventually they discover a dome over the area.
- The dome has several distortion areas that allow travel to other places.
- There is a third character, a very attractive second woman, who is initially discovered on a plinth in the basement of the house.  The plinth has an obvious lever on it.
- There are two other empty plinths in the basement, presumably where the first man and woman were.
- The first woman pulls the lever and awakens the second woman.  When asked why she did it, she answers something like, "It needed to be done."

This was the first installment and I have no idea what the name of it was, or the author.  I know it's not much to go on, but it would satisfy a long-running mystery for me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're looking for *Six Gates from Limbo* by J.T. McIntosh. First serialized in *Worlds of IF* magazine, beginning in January, 1969, later published in paperback.

Rex wakes in this paradise alone, no memories of who he is. He comes to realize that he is in an artificial, domed environment. There are six "spatial distortions;" gates, he later finds goes to other worlds. He finds a house with 3 suspended animation chambers, one empty, which he came from, and two others, each containing a woman; Regina and Venus. Regina wakes and they start to explore the gates. I'm not remembering specifically that Regina pulls a switch to wake Venus.
We come to find out that Rex has the combined mental essence of a million people who have suicided and will decide how to save the galactic civilization.

[image] [image]

All issues of *Worlds of IF* have been made available via the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/ifmagazine?&sort=-date&page=3):

- [January 1969 issue](https://archive.org/details/1969-01_IF); *Six Gates to Limbo* starts at page 5
- [February 1969 issue](https://archive.org/details/1969-02_IF); *Six Gates to Limbo* starts at page 108

Comment: That's it!  Thanks so much!  I'm sure you've heard it before, but that one's been bugging me on and off for a very long time.  Edit:  I was able to find the book as an ebook on barnes & noble to boot.  Thanks again.

Comment: Strangely enough, on _Worlds of IF_ it was published as _Six Gates **to** Limbo_, while the paperback is titled _Six Gates **from** Limbo_. Is it the same story / a retelling / a sequel / something else?